# Difference between H5BP, Responsive and Bootstrap, can we combine them?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html5boilerplate

I am new to Responsive designing, i just wants to know to the difference between h5bp, responsive and bootstrap websites.

And can we combine them with lightweight and without un-required things.?

Regards,
Sopo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 Boilerplate is a starting point, it include all of the necessary elements that you will need to begin building a web page with html. Have the knowledge of many people about how is the structure right of a web page html. You can use the index.html provided and modify it to your like.

Responsive is to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices. So you will can see your web pages in cellphones, ipad, iphones, desktop computer without problems. Example, when you see a old web page in your cellphone you have make zoom and the web page have a view  very small. When you build a responsive web page, it will have a big view and nice in all the devices.

Bootstrap is sleek, intuitive, and powerful mobile first front-end framework for faster and easier web development. it has many components and examples about forms, sliders, navbars, menu, buttons, links, etc. So  you will can build a web page in short time. Bootstrap is responsive.

Yes, you can combine the tree concepts, Bootstrap use the responsive concept and is used by many web developers, i have used HTML5 Boilerplate and Bootstrap and in short time i can build many things. :D